# What does this double entendre じゃなかったらいいのかよ mean?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, katakana, kana

「テレビ番組を勝手にアップロードするのは違法だからな」

「10年以下の懲役か1000万円以下の罰金か、その両方だ」

Teacher talking to 3 students:
It's illegal to upload TV programs without permission.

You can get up to 10 years of hard labor... ...10 million yen in fines... ...or both.

*This is where my understanding gets a little blurry*

「あぁ？勝手じゃなかったらいいのかよ」

「ヨシオがいいっつったらいいのかよ？」

Student A:
Huh?/Really?/Is that true? So would it be okay if it was permissible?

Student A points to ヨシオ coming up the stairs:
If Yoshio says its all right is it all right?

Comment: The way I understand 勝手 is "doing as one pleases". So the student is possibly implying that he didn't really do it of his own free will. Maybe he was forced / coerced into it by that ヨシオ　guy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The teacher used the word 勝手 to mean “without permission” in a legal sense. The student understood it as meaning “as one pleases,” “of one’s own free will,” or something like that. He is asking if he can upload TV programs if ヨシオ says OK because that’s, by his logic, 勝手じゃない.